# Calling function defined with function type interface

Tags: typescript

Following the interfaces section of the [TypeScript docus](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) I'm having problems with the function types.  The example given is as below:

```
interface SearchFunc {
  (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

let mySearch: SearchFunc;
mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
  let result = source.search(subString);
  return result > -1;
}
```

How can I use this new function? I've tried various options but am always given the following error "error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

```
let isInString = mySearch({source: 'abcdefg', subString: 'c'}) // Error!
```

Comment: does this work `let isInString = mySearch('abcdefg', 'c')`?

Comment: Yes, I can't believe how long I spent trying to pass in various objects! Thankyou

Comment: okay. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has 2 strings as parameters and you are passing an object with 2 string properties.

So, `let isInString = mySearch('abcdefg', 'c')` should call the function with proper arguments.